# How to change checkbox color in angular

Tags: angular

I need to change the checkbox color when it is in disabled.

**app.component.html:**

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [disabled]="item.disabled" [checked]="item.checked">
```

This is the code working in CSS only on hover but that should be disabled all the time.

**CSS:**

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label:hover::before {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d5;
}
```

Comment: are you using any css framework like angular material or creating custom checkbox ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style a checkbox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: No @YongShun nothing was working

Comment: Can you please create a stackbliz for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like below.

html

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
  <label>Disabled</label>
</div>

<br />

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label>Abled</label>
</div>
```

css

```
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] + label {
  padding-left: 1.85714em;
}

input[type='checkbox']:disabled + label::before {
  background: #7e7eda;
}
input[type='checkbox']:disabled + label:hover::before {
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d5;
}

input[type='checkbox'] + label:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.21428571rem;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.1s ease, opacity 0.1s ease;
  transition: border 0.1s ease, opacity 0.1s ease;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d5;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ label:before {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.35);
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```

You can check [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fz9g9o)

Let me know if you face any issue.